# What cost to creating vampires

Tags: vampires, blood

Assume a world in which vampirism is totally unlike how it is usually portrayed in Bram Stoker's Dracula, Anne Rice novels, True Blood etc. Instead it's somewhat analogous to a disease where the victim's digestive system undergoes a transformation that enables it to digest only blood. The only other side effect is immortality (barring accidents, violence etc.). Creation of new vampires is done the usual way, i.e. by having a vampire drain them of their blood.

In such a world why would it be bad for vampires to create new ones from humans on the brink of death? I thought of two options:

1. It somehow contaminates their own blood.
2. It's taboo for some reason.

Any other reasons you can think of? Or something that could make my own ideas more interesting?

Comment: Welcome to WorldBuilding *Johnny*! I am afraid you are slightly misunderstanding the sites scope. Your question reads like a poll for opinions on what possible options could be or better ways to frame your options. This looks quite "opinion-based" to me as every somewhat sensible answer is exactly equally valid without any criteria on what makes an answer *valid* and what makes an answer *good*. I am voting to temporarily put this on hold until you [edit] it to have some criteria. If you have a moment please take the [tour] and visit the [help] to learn more about the site. Have fun!

Comment: Most settings with vampires have a solution to this issue. They differ because it is dependent on the settings. Basically this is something that the person "making" the vampires decides. Which is why your question is getting those votes to close. You probably should add some criteria of what kind of effect you are going for or just decide it yourself. Asking if your solution to the issue makes sense would be a valid question usually.

Comment: Oh, I did not VTC because you can answer this by giving a list of solutions you have seen used and expanding it a little to be more generic. More complete lists would be objectively better than shorter lists and an answer with a single solution is just a list of one item. Editing the question to explicitly ask for a list or overview of possible solutions might help with those votes to close?

Answer (score 5):

In an ideal world (for the vampire), a vampire would be the only vampire in a world that had forgotten about vampires. New vampires don't represent a continuation of a genetic line, that becomes redundant with immortality, the thing that matters to an immortal is the preservation of the self.

**New vampires are competition.**

They represent an increased risk that the world will once again remember vampires and how to deal with them.

You do not have to justify why a vampire wouldn't create more vampires but rather why they would.

Comment: The old predator-prey relationship. Increase the number of predators and the ratio of prey to predator goes down. Indeed the real question should be why would vampires create more of their own kind.